# Skip an iteration in Talend

Tags: integration, talend

How do I skip an iteration in Talend when using the tFlowToIterate component?

Attaching an image of my talend job where I have 3 different iterations originating from the Flow to iterate component. Is there a way to skip iterate2 and iterate3 if a value in iterate1 is null?

Or do i need to design this in a different way?

[image: Talend job screenshot]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi! Are you saying that iterate2 and 3 are dependent on a value retrieved in iterate1?

Comment: For iterate2 & iterate3 you might put a `tJava` component and put logic to `break` from the code whenever you receive data as null.

Comment: You could put a tJava in front of tREST in iterate2 and 3, and link it to tREST with an If trigger. Inside the If condition you test the value that you retrieved in iterate1 and stored in a global variable.

Comment: @Screwtape : Yes, they are.

Comment: @Abhishek : The problem I am facing is with the `tREST` component. I am not able to link a main row to the `tREST` component. The input lines it accepts are "iterate", "on component ok", "run if" etc. However, if I put a `tJava` and try to link a main row to the tREST component, it does not accept it.

Comment: @iMezouar : That's a good idea. I will try that and let you know

Comment: @iMezouar : That worked! Thank you!